# Swap columns in bash using SED without using loop

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I'm new to Sed, I'm trying to learn some pattern using Sed. 
I got a filenamne.txt that has the following entry:

> ppp/jjj   qqq/kkk   rrr/lll

My goal is to swap the word before the slash and the word after the slash in each of the three *word1/word2* columns:

> jjj/ppp kkk/qqq lll/rrr

I tried using `sed –re ‘s!(.*)(/)(.*)!\1\2\!’ filename.txt`, but it didn't work. Any idea how can I go about it?

Comment: `\1\2` keeps the columns in the same order. It should be `\2\1` to swap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo "ppp/jjj qqq/kkk rrr/lll" | sed -e 's/$/ /' -e 's!\([^/]*\)/\([^ ]*\) !\2/\1 !g'
jjj/ppp kkk/qqq lll/rrr
```

Comment: You add a space that could be removed to clean up.  You could perhaps avoid having to add the space if you used a positive character class such as `[a-zA-Z]` — that would fit the example cleanly, but it depends on what the real as opposed to example data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use replacement in `perl` command-line is a lot more straight-forward :-

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)\/(\w+)/$2\/$1/g' file
jjj/ppp kkk/qqq lll/rrr
```

Comment: that's no more straight forward than the equivalent GNU sed: `sed -E 's#(\w+)/(\w+)#\2/\1#g' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's#\([^ ]*\)/\([^ ]*\)#\2/\1#g' file
jjj/ppp kkk/qqq lll/rrr
```